# Extract lines from File2 already found File1

Tags: linux, bash

Using linux commandline, i need to output the lines from text **file2** that are already found in **file1**.

**File1**:

```
C
A
G
E
B
D
H
F
```

**File2**:

```
N
I
H
J
K
M
D
L
A
```

**Output**:

```
A
D
H
```

Thanks!

Comment: I had already tested `grep -f` but getting an [error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961219/extract-lines-from-file2-already-found-file1#comment49977455_30961263).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more flexible tool to use would be `awk`

```
awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0]++; next} $1 in lines'
```

**Example**

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{lines[$0]++; next} $1 in lines' file1 file2
H
D
A
```

**What it does?**

- `NR==FNR{lines[$0]++; next}`

  - `NR==FNR` checks if the file number of records is equal to the overall number of records. This is true only for the first file, `file1`
  - `lines[$0]++` Here we create an associative array with the line, `$0` in file 1 as index.
- `$0 in lines` This line works only for the second file because of the `next` in previous action. This checks if the line in file 2 is there in the saved array `lines`, if yes the default action of printing the entire line is taken

---

`Awk` is more flexible than the `grep` as you can columns in file1 with any column in file 2 and decides to print any column rather than printing the entire line

Comment: @EdMorton I missed that. Updated in answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for the tools 'grep'

Check this out.

Lets say you have inputs in `file1` & `file2` files

```
grep -f file1 file2
```

will return you

```
H
D
A
```

Comment: Why on earth are you piping to `awk`?? `grep -f file1 file2` is all you need.

Comment: No problem, that's why there was no downvote, just confusing `:p`

Comment: only to add more correct will be grep -f file2 file1

Comment: @Fawzan using **grep** when i trying to extract lines found on [abpjf](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/k2jp/abp-japanese-filters/master/abpjf.txt) already found on [easylist](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt) i get this error message: `grep: failed pairing [ or [^`

Comment: Is this relevant to this question? or a separate question?

Comment: I'd add `-x` to speed up the matching a bit.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `comm` utility does, but you have to sort the files first: To get the lines in common between the 2 files:

```
comm -12 <(sort File1) <(sort File2)
```